# libsiftgpu.so not found on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gpu, sift

I tyr to install VisualSFM for 3d reconstruction from 2d multi-images. I install visualsfm gui. But I don't generate 3d reconstruction yet. I must install some dependencies.

[Installation guide](http://www.10flow.com/2012/08/15/building-visualsfm-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-desktop-64-bit/) says that run make file to install siftgpu. I do it but I get an error : `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lI`L.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and might be you have also solved it like me. If not then you can download complete VisualSfM package from [GitHub](https://github.com/anders-dc/vsfm-linux-x86_64). You can use the below codes for installing its dependencies and installation of complete package. Please download the zip file first.

to install dependencies`$ make install-reqs`
to install complete package `./visualsfm.sh`

Comment: Please post relevant code sections from external links into the answer body.  Answers with external links are useless if the link goes dead.